# Chroot Ubuntu 21.10 GDBus Problem

Tags: apt

I'm using Ubuntu 21.10 via chroot but `apt` and `gnome-session` give this error:

```
Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.Spawn.PermissionsInvalid: The permission of the setuid helper is not correct
```

This solution is suggested for this problem but my android doesn't have the usr folder either:

```
sudo chmod u+s /usr/lib/dbus-1.0/dbus-daemon-launch-helper
```

First of all, I mounted / as rw myself:

```
mount -o rw,remount /
```

Then I try to create it with the `mkdir usr` command and it says there is no room for me:

```
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘usr’: No space left on device
```

Specs:

Android 11 (R) Aarch64

Redmi Note 10S 6/128 (Secret)

Termux 0.118